# Git using alias throws branch name required

Tags: git, bash, alias

I've tried to add a custom alias in git, but when I'm executing it, I get the error message: `branch name required`.

I've executed this command for adding the alias:

```
git config --global alias.dfrm 'branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d'
```

This command removes all branches that are merged besides `dev` and `master`.

I also tried to modify the command, but that does not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very likely because the pipeline `git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)"` doesn't output anything, so `xargs` executes `git branch -d` with no arguments. If you have GNU `xargs`, you can use its `-r` switch (that makes `xargs` not run the command if there are no arguments read). But I'm not sure your design is very good, though.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That should be an answer. (I just verified that it is correct btw.)